# Saving a file to a specific folder using Django Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form that I am rendering with a `FileField()`

After the form is submitted this is what I am doing in my views.

```
def complete(request):
    file = request.POST.get('my_uploaded_file')

    ...
    get a instance of my object that this is saving to
    ...

    inst.file = file
    inst.save()

    return render(request, 'myapp/mypage.html')
```

My model looks like this:

```
class MyUpload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='user_uploads/')
```

And my Forms

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(label='File')
```

Now when I select a file and click submit it, the file is updated in the model. When I try to view the image I get a 404 Error.

This is the link it is linking me to in the admin panel

```
http://localhost:8000/media/Roku.pcapng
```

EDIT:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and my templates is modified

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT)],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

File Structure

```
djang_project
-app1
-app2
-app3
-app4
-media
--my_templates
--profile_pics
--user_logs
-app5
-static
-app6
.gitignore
.manage.py
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('adobe/',  include('adobeparser.urls')),
    path('segment/',  include('jsonparser.urls')),
    path('omega/', include('omegavalidator.urls')),
    path('fsrevamp/', include('fsrevamp.urls')),
    path('', root_views.home, name='root-home'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please post the MEDIA elements from your settings.py and urls.py files. The URL you posted should maybe have user_uploads/ somewhere in it, so it appears to be a bad setting.

Comment: @MichaelHawkins I updated.

Comment: Try manually entering the url like this and see what happens: http://localhost:8000/media/user_uploads/Roku.pcapng

Comment: Just 404. I looked and the file is not uploaded at that location.

Comment: Can you post your folder structure?

Comment: I added it. Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "user_uploads" folder under media

Comment: I added the folder and still same thing.

Comment: Can you post the MEDIA path in your urls.py? Also, is the file actually being uploaded to the folder?

Comment: I pasted my main urls.py and no I am not finding the file anywhere.

Comment: I posted an answer I think will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. It appears you are trying to get the file from request.POST when you should be getting it from request.FILES like so:

```
file = request.FILES.get('my_uploaded_file')
upload = MyUpload.objects.create(file=file)
upload.save()
...
```

Or:

```
form = myForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
   # do something with the file
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Awesome. That was it. I tried understanding the docs but my Django experience is low. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! Best of luck!